# One letter word on the end of line (justify)

Tags: html, css

I wonder what I can do if I have one letter word on the end of text line, for example:

```
"Hello my name is John Smith, and I
am a freshman!"
```

How can I move "I" to the next line, and have justified the entire line? Because when I put `<br>` then justify crashes.

Here's jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P3xYv/

Comment: Can you provide us with your code? Or a Jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: This is a simple code with only width, and text-align: justify. I have on the end of line one letter word, and I don't know how to move it to the next line without losing justify in this line. Because <br> doesn't work, it moves one letter word to the next line, but the line from which this one letter is, loses justify.

Comment: Sorry, but even than, you need to publish your code, so we can see not only your efforts but even where it goes wrong.

Comment: Based on the info we have, decreasing the width of the container should work http://jsfiddle.net/ekG66/. **You really need to include more info.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a NO-BREAK SPACE U+00A0 between two words, instead of normal whitespace (like space or line break), browsers will keep those words together, on one line. Example:

```
"Hello my name is John Smith, and I&nbsp;am
a freshman!"
```

Here I have used the named character reference `&nbsp;`, but you can also use the NO-BREAK SPACE itself if you know how to type it in your authoring environment and have properly declared the character encoding. In most editing programs, NO-BREAK SPACE looks just like a normal space.

This is independent of text justification. In the old days, browsers used to treat NO-BREAK SPACE as non-stretchable in justification. But nowadays it is treated like space in justification, i.e. it gets its share of added spacing.

If you’d like to have a non-breaking non-stretchable space between words, you’d need a more complicated approach. You would use U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE or some other [fixed-width space](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) and you wrap the words in an element where [line breaking is forbidden](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html) with HTML or CSS. For example, instead of `I&nbsp;am` you would write `<nobr>I&#x2005;am</nobr>` or, more clumsily but conforming to “standards”, `<span style="white-space: nowrap">I&#x2005;am</span>`. There is no guarantee that this will work in the future, though; there is no requirement in specifications that browsers support fixed-width characters this way (but this is a simple and natural implementation, and the current one).